# seaborn exclude columns in clustering

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have a dataset containing 200 rows and 97 columns, which I have stored as a pandas dataframe.

I am plotting this dataframe with seaborn, using clustermap, like this:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

sns.set(rc={'axes.facecolor':'white', 'figure.facecolor':'white'})
cmap=ListedColormap(["white", "lightgray", "blue", "red", "cornflowerblue", "darkcyan", "pink", "violet"])
g = sns.clustermap(df,method="complete", metric="hamming",row_cluster=True, 
col_cluster=False, figsize=(10, 20), cmap=cmap)
plt.setp(g.ax_heatmap.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0) 
plt.show()
```

However, I have just realized that I would like to plot it just like this, but I do not want the two first columns of my data frame to be included in the distance calculations.

Suggestions of how I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use `iloc` to do your trimming

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

sns.set(rc={'axes.facecolor':'white', 'figure.facecolor':'white'})
cmap=ListedColormap(["white", "lightgray", "blue", "red", "cornflowerblue", "darkcyan", "pink", "violet"])
g = sns.clustermap(
    df.iloc[:, 2:], method="complete", metric="hamming", row_cluster=True,
    col_cluster=False, figsize=(10, 20), cmap=cmap)
plt.setp(g.ax_heatmap.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0) 
plt.show()
```